# regex match specfic string without specfic trailing character

Tags: regular-expression

This has me stumped

I have a large C source file which has a variable that must always be added to like this:

```
CycleCounter += SomeValue
```

The some value isn't important.

There are several hundred lines like this in the code in a source file with several thousand lines. I'm trying to ensure all assignments are with added and accidentally assigned or subtracted.

I want find all occurrences where CycleCounter is not followed by a '+' or some white space and a '+'

I tried this expression :

```
CycleCounter\s*[^+]
```

but in this example it also matches where a '+' does occur.

It matches case 1 as well but I only want it to match cases 2 & 3 which do not have a trailing '+'.

```
if (postbyte & 0x80)
{
    switch (postbyte & 0x1F)
    {
    case 0: // Post inc by 1
        ea = (*xfreg16[Register]);
        (*xfreg16[Register])++;
        CycleCounter+=NatEmuCycles21; // good. expression correctly ignored this
        break;

    case 1: // post in by 2
        ea = (*xfreg16[Register]);
        (*xfreg16[Register]) += 2;
        CycleCounter += NatEmuCycles32; // good. expression incorrectly identified 
        break;

    case 2: // pre dec by 1
        (*xfreg16[Register]) -= 1;
        ea = (*xfreg16[Register]);
        CycleCounter -= NatEmuCycles21;  // mistake, subtracted. expression correctly identified
        break;

    case 3: // pre dec by 2
        (*xfreg16[Register]) -= 2;
        ea = (*xfreg16[Register]);
        CycleCounter = NatEmuCycles32; // mistake, assigned. expression correctly identified
        break;

    case 4: // no offset
        ea = (*xfreg16[Register]);
        break;
```

Comment: What regex tool, specifically? if it supports PCRE, then you should be able to use negative lookahead, like `CycleCounter(?!\s*[+]=)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If using Perl Compatible Regular Expressions (PCRE), adding a `+` after `\s*` will greedily match those zero more spaces, preventing `[^+]` from matching the spaces. Eg. using `grep` with `-P` to use PCRE (a GNU grep option) and also `-n` to show line numbers:

```
grep -Pn 'CycleCounter\s*+[^+]' file
```

Another PCRE:

```
grep -Pn 'CycleCounter(?!\s*\+)' file
```

This time using negative lookahead to specify `not followed a '+' or some white space and a '+'`.

---

You could use `sed` to remove unwanted lines from output:

```
sed '/CycleCounter/!d; /CycleCounter[[:space:]]*+/d; =' file
```

Delete any line which doesn't contain CycleCounter, also delete any line that does contain CycleCounter followed by any space and a '+'. `=` to print line numbers.

Answer (score 1):

It's all about the `*` quantifier. `\s*` - this means that there may be no matches, and the second expression [^+] will match a whitespace character immediately after the word `CycleCounter`.

```
grep 'CycleCounter\s\+[^+]'
```

or

```
grep 'CycleCounter\s*[^+]='
```

or

```
grep 'CycleCounter\s*[^+ ]'
```

Comment: Neither of these worked.  Unfortunately my example didn't cover all possibilities and second fails with 'CycleCounter=...' and the first just fails in most cases.

Comment: `grep 'CycleCounter\s*[^+ ]'`. I added to answer.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to match on `CycleCounter` provided it's *not* followed by optional whitespace and `+`, you can use perl's negative look-ahead operator:

```
grep -P 'CycleCounter(?!\s*\+)'
```

(here assuming a `grep` implementation that supports `-P` for perl-like regexps).

If you want to match on `CycleCounter` provided it's followed by optional whitespace and a character that is neither `+` nor whitespace:

```
grep 'CycleCounter[[:space:]]*[^+[:space:]]'
```

`[[:space:]]` is the POSIX regexp equivalent of Perl's `\s`. Some `grep` implementations also support `\s` in their BREs/EREs as an extension, but not inside bracket expressions where `[\s]` is required by POSIX to match on either `\` or `s`.

In any case while both `[[:space:]]` and `\s` would match on a newline character, `grep` by default works on the contents of one line at a time (not including the newline delimiter), so both would still match on the first line of:

```
   CycleCounter
     += 12;
```

for instance.

With `pcregrep` (that comes with PCRE, a library that implements perl-like regexps and used by most of the `grep` implementations that support a `-P` option), you could do:

```
pcregrep -M '(?s)CycleCounter(?!\s*\+).*?;'
```

Where `-M` enables a multi-line mode and `(?s)` causes `.` to also match on newline, and `.*?;` is used to make sure the full C statement up to the next `;` character is printed.

Of course, it could still be fooled with things like:

```
CycleCounter // blah ;
  += (c == ';')
  + 3;
```

Also note that they would match on `MyCycleCounter2 += 3`. To avoid that you could add word boundary operators around `CycleCounter`. In Perl, that's `\bCycleCounter\b`. There's no POSIX regex equivalent though some `grep` implementations also support `\b`, or support `\<CycleCounter\>` or `[[:<:]]CycleCounter[[:>:]]` as an extension.